# Network Analysis Service Area Algorithm QGIS 3.16

Tags: qgis, service-area

I've been using ORS Tools to run my service area analysis for my research, because it was easier and quicker for me to get an isochrone, instead of the standard network analysis tools from QGIS, that needed me some extra steps to turn the road network into an isochrone.

I'm really curious on how it works. Are there any source I can use to study on the algorithm or the coding for this? I've tried looking for the algorithm behind ORS tools, but i didnt find any yet. Best I got was https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html for the, I'm assuming, coding behind service area analysis from the standard QGIS tools. I'm basically blind towards coding, Python, and stuff. I'm hoping to get a brief surface level explanation on how things work to get the end result.